# Object Detection Images folder read return <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error

Tags: python, deep-learning, object-detection

I am creating a python script to analyse and detect objects from jpg images in test images folder in object detection folder. Running object detection API jupyter notebook dose work fine in reading and detecting object from test images folder. However running the code in pyhton script using CMD or python shell gives the following error:

```
   image = cv2.imread(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS)
SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error
```

The code related to the error:

```
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'D:/New folder/models/research/object_detection/test_images'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 30) ]

# Load image using OpenCV and
# expand image dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
# i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
image = cv2.imread(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS)
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_rgb, axis=0)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: see `print(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS)` and you will see what is problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `TEST_IMAGE_PATHS` which has list with paths but `imread()` needs single path.

If you want to load single image then you have to use index - ie. `[0]` for first image

```
image = cv2.imread(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS[0])
```

If you want to work with all images then you have to use `for`-loop

```
all_images = []

for path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
    image = cv2.imread(path)
    # keep on list
    all_images.append(image)
```

Or even proces all images in the same loop

```
all_images_expanded = []

for path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
    image = cv2.imread(path)
    image = cv2.imread(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS)
    image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_rgb, axis=0)
    # keep on list
    all_images_expanded.append(image_expanded)
```